# Passing value to a previous scene in navigation controller

Tags: swift

Could anyone tell me how can I pass value from a second scene in the navigation controller in swift to the first one that actually drives to this second one by some button.I cannot use prepare for segue function because it is only called when moving form the tail of the segue to its head.

Comment: You use delegates for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for delegate pattern!

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func secondViewController(controller: SecondViewController, passVariable variable: Int)
}

class SecondViewController {
    weak var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

    ...
    func ButtonTappped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.secondViewController(self, passVariable: 10)
    }
}


class FirstViewController: SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }

    // MARK: SecondViewControllerDelegate
    func secondViewController(controller: SecondViewController, passVariable variable: Int) {
        // Here we go!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, is there more explanation about what you wrote? because I didn't understand most of it.